# c# algorithm for searching terms in dictionary

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, dictionary

I am trying to develop a dictionary which will retrieve terms and definitions from database and show to the user his specific term and its definition.
The problem is how dictionaries search the terms when user types in search field ?

(also advice me using database is good OR there's another way)

Comment: What code do you have so far that is not working? How does what it is doing differ from what you expect? Are any exceptions being thrown, and if so, what are they? The more specifics you can provide about the problem, the more likely you are to get an answer that solves the issue.

Comment: i am completely beginner to c# right now. So far, i have designed an interface for dictionary in which one column is for terms other is for definitions and a 'search' field. To my plan, when user will type characters in search field, all the relating terms should appear in term column. After this, if user clicks a specific term, its definition should appear in definition column.

Comment: Unfortunately, the purpose of this site is not to write code for you, but to help you with problems that you may encounter while attempting to write code for yourself. Study, write some code and come back when you've hit a specific problem that you can't find an answer to or run into a specific concept that you just don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Its usually a good idea to provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of code (C# in your case) you have put together, describe the result you would like and how that differs from the result you are getting.  By providing a MWE you increase the chances of getting a productive answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a database table with columns 'term_name', and 'term_definition'

Use the SQL operator LIKE
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE 'term_name' LIKE '%query%'
```

Notice that the '%' symbol is a wildcard, so you could only append it to the end of the query if you wanted them to beable to search words that start with their query rather than having racecar come up when searching car.

Comment: Thanks for concern. Your code is for sql but how is  possible to embed it with c# application??

Comment: Setup a sql server, as that is probably your safest bet for a database like you mentioned.  C# can then access this data store. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Comment: If you are looking for away to do the same sort of pattern matching in C# try these functions 
    string.Contains("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE '%pattern%'
    string.StartsWith("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE 'pattern%'
    string.EndsWith("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE '%pattern'

Comment: maybe this sounds crazy but as a beginner I have to ask: how to setup a sql server ?
(i am using visual studio)

Comment: Easiest way is probably SQLite, http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/